# Windows Live ID giving back different User Token for the same User on different Apps?

Tags: windows-live-id, windows-live

**Windows Live ID seems to be giving back a different User Token for the same User on different Apps.**

Heres the scoop.

Windows Live ID is supposed (i think) to give me Unique User Token.
I want to use this to identify the user.
My App is 2 parts ... 1 = ASP.NET webapp...2 is WPF.
(Same DB / User Table)

**Problem:**

When user logs in to ASP.Net - I get UserToken = 00202009399.

When user logs in to WPF - I get UserToken = 00829909233.

**Question:**

- Is this a glich? If so - what is a
  work around?

(If this is planned behaviour - I can only think MS wants to separate User Tokens per Application or Domain)

- Is there a setting to Tell LiveID
  that these 2 differnt Apps (WPf &
  ASP.Net ) are from same
  Orginization/Owner/Azure Account?

Comment: You sure the token is not more like a session token? in which it will always be different...

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late in the game. Windows Live ID provides you with a unique, site-specific identifier for each Windows Live user who signs in to your site. It is designed that way to allow user confidentiality and security from one site to the next.

> Is there a setting to Tell LiveID that these 2 differnt Apps (WPf & ASP.Net ) are from same Orginization/Owner/Azure Account?

If you want the to have the same identifier you will have to use the same App Id. If you are wanting to maintain the part of the application you are signing in from you can use the [context Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676638.aspx) to set the path to return too the only requirment is that they have to be in the same Domain you set when registering your application.